# Threading over a list of lists of lists and a list of atomic expressions

Tags: list-manipulation

Although I solved the following problem using `MapThread`, I'm curious about why `Thread` does not work as I expect it to here.

Given two lists of length n, where the first list is a list of lists of lists and the second is a list of atomic expressions, such as:

```
list1 = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {9, 8}}};
list2 = {"a", "b"};
```

and where `list1[[n]]` can contain 1 or more lists of atomic expressions. I would like to create a single list that places the nth element of the second list at the end of every sublist of `list1[[n]]`, producing:

```
{{{1, 2, "a"}, {3, 4, 5, "a"}}, {{1, 3, 5, "b"}, {9, 8, "b"}}}
```

I first tried the following

```
appendTo[ll_, item_] := Map[Append[#, item] &, ll];
Thread[appendTo[list1, list2]]
```

But this returns:

```
{{{1, 2}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {9, 8}}, {{"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}}}
```

even though threading an undefined function seems to produce the right expressions:

```
Thread[f[a, b]]
{f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, "a"], f[{{1, 3, 5}, {9, 8}}, "b"]}
```

`MapThread` works fine:

```
MapThread[appendTo, {list1, list2}]
{{{1, 2, "a"}, {3, 4, 5, "a"}}, {{1, 3, 5, "b"}, {9, 8, "b"}}}
```

So why is `Thread` producing the behavior shown above instead of giving the same result as `MapThread`?

Threading `Rule` on the same lists also produces what I expect:

```
Thread[Rule[list1, list2]]
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}} -> "a", {{1, 3, 5}, {9, 8}} -> "b"}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers already posted, you can look [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node481.html), where I discussed this exact issue.

Comment: Incidentally, `Inner` is good for this kind of transformation: `Inner[Append, list1, list2, List]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer: [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) does not have the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html), so its contents are executed before it processes them.

But, it is not quite that simple. If you add `HoldAll`, you still don't get what you want

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Thread},
 SetAttributes[Thread, HoldAll];
 Thread[appendTo[list1, list2]]
]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {"a", "b"}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {9, 8}, {"a", "b"}}} *)
```

which implies that in this form only the first list is threaded over.

---

Note, I used [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/52) to retain the behavior of `Thread` while not allowing my modifications to leak.

Comment: I understand now. This also explains why Rule works, unlike appendTo: when Rule is evaluated it expands to an expression that when operated on by Thread produces the result shown above.

Comment: " in this form only the first list is threaded over" this explanation isn't right, in this case nothing is threaded over, the output is the same as that of `appendTo[list1, list2]`. See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108627/1871) for more information.

Comment: @xzczd you're absolutely correct. I must have been asleep when I wrote this.

Answer (score 8):

There is a much simpler alternative here - to use the `Block` trick. What we need is to give `appendTo` a case of temporal amnesia, which is what `Block` excels at:

```
Block[{appendTo}, Thread[appendTo[list1, list2]]]
```

Answer (score 7):

As rcollyer already pointed out, `appendTo` is evaluated as parameter to `Thread`. You can of course simply `Hold` it and release it after the `Thread`:

```
Thread[Hold[appendTo][list1, list2]] // ReleaseHold

(* {{{1, 2, "a"}, {3, 4, 5, "a"}}, {{1, 3, 5, "b"}, {9, 8, "b"}}} *)
```

There is another possibility which is clear and needs no further adjustment like `Hold` or `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``

```
appendTo @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

Comment: Another route: `Thread[f[list1, list2]] /. f -> appendTo`