# Map works but Thread doesn't

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

This question may be trivial, but I can't get past it for the life of me.

I have $n$ matrices of dimension $p_i \times N_i$, with $i$ indexing the $n$-set. I also have $n$ vectors of the appropriate length.

I'm looking to create a list of the inner products. This works (obviously):

```
MapThread[Dot[#1,#2]&,{nmats,nvecs}]
```

The problem comes in when I pass in lists of `nmats`. That is, I have $C$ copies of `nmats` stored in `cnmats` and want to collect the above for each. For some reason `Map`ping works,

```
MapThread[Dot[#1,#2]&,{#,nvecs}]&/@cnmats
```

but `Thread`ing doesnt

```
Thread[MapThread[Dot[#1,#2]&,{#,nvecs}]&[cnmats]]
```

Replacing `MapThread` with `Table` moves the error to `Dot: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.`

The error returned is:

```
Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of (MapThread expression);
dimensions are n and C
```

$C$ and $N_i$ are $O(10^5)$, $p$ is $O(1)$, so I favor `Thread` for the speed advantage.

Why can't I thread here? How can I implement this differently to benefit from threading?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(14121)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14121/121),
[(37274)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37274/121),
[(45240)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45240/121)

Comment: Thank you sir, this will help me brush up on Threading in mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here has been explained in the posts linked by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard): `Thread` doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute so the inner code i.e. `MapThread[Dot[#1,#2]&,{#,nvecs}]&[cnmats]` will evaluate before `Thread` begins to work.

I write this answer just to highlight a property of `Thread`, which has actually be mentioned but not emphasized in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37276/1871), that is, like `Module` and `Manipulate`, the… er… structure to be `Thread`ed must **explicitly exists** inside `Thread`.

This property isn't eye-catching because, as mentioned above, `Thread` doesn't hold its arguments so usually the structure to be `Thread`ed will become explicit after automatic evaluation, but it'll easily show up once you tried to control the evaluation order. For example:

```
D[{x, y}, {x, y}]
(* Derivative[y, 0][List][x, y] *)

Thread@D[{x, y}, {x, y}]
(* Derivative[y, 0][List][x, y] *)

Thread@Unevaluated@D[{x, y}, {x, y}]
(* {1, 1} *)

xy = {x, y}; Thread@Unevaluated@D[xy, xy]
(* Derivative[y, 0][List][x, y] *)
```

Output of the fourth sample is the same as the first two, what happened? Let's `Trace` it:

```
Thread@Unevaluated@D[xy, xy] // Trace
```

[image]

apparently `Thread` doesn't "see" the `{x, y}` so `D[xy, xy]` is still `D[xy, xy]` afterwards.

To fix the problem, one need to adjust the evaluation order further, here are 2 approaches:

```
With[{xy = {x, y}}, Thread@Unevaluated@D[xy, xy]]
Clear@xy;
Hold@Thread@Unevaluated@D[xy, xy] /. xy -> {x, y} // ReleaseHold
```

Back to your problem, if you want to insist on `Thread` (will it really be faster?), then

```
With[{cnmats = cnmats}, 
 Thread[Unevaluated[MapThread[Dot[#1, #2] &, {#, nvecs}] &[cnmats]]]]
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you much! The speedup turned out to be 10%: not as much as I had hoped for.